# Libgdx. Forcing the Skin json to generate and load needed BitmapFont thanks to FreeTypeFontGenerator

Tags: json, fonts, libgdx, assets, skin

Well, I managed to use FreeType fonts generated by my assetManager in my json skin, but not in a satisfying way. The following code works.

```
/* Manager loaders */
manager = new AssetManager();
InternalFileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
manager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
manager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

/* Generating the font with the assetManager */
FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter param = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
param.fontFileName = "UI/kenvector_future.ttf";
manager.load("myfont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, param);
manager.finishLoadingAsset("myfont.ttf");
BitmapFont newFont = manager.get("myfont.ttf");

/* Passing the name in the SkinLoader parameter */
ObjectMap<String, Object> oMap = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
oMap.put("myfont", newFont);
manager.load("UI/skin.json", Skin.class, new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("UI/skin.atlas", oMap));
```

And the json

```
{
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
        arial-15: {
            file: com/badlogic/gdx/utils/arial-15.fnt
        }
    },
    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
        textButton: {
            up: buttonLong_blue,
            down: buttonLong_blue_pressed,
            font: arial-15
        },
        textButton2: {
            up: buttonLong_beige,
            down: buttonLong_beige_pressed,
            font: myfont
        }
    },
}
```

It works, but I would like to get rid of the Generating part of this code (below "Generating blablabla assetManager") as well as the oMap part.

I tried to add myfont in the bitmap part, I tried to add a node for FreeTypeFontLoader and FreeTypeFontLoader parameter. It didn't work.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: I think I found a way to do it, but it would be way more complicated than what you're doing above. Subclassing Skin to change the way the Json reader handles BitmapFont, creating a Loader for your subclass, registering the loader and your subclass with AssetManager.

Comment: Indeed it would be complicated ^^ I wanted to call load for everything I need in a row and let the update method load them so I can rely on the getProcess method. But it seems I have to wait for some assets, the fonts, to be loaded before I can load my skin. Thank you for your help these last few days.